# Using process.env vars in Ember

Tags: node.js, ember.js, environment-variables, ember-cli

This may be a dumb question, but how to get access to `process.env` vars inside of my ember app? I tried to access `process.env` in one of my controllers, but I received an error that process was not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't have access to **process.env** since this is **node.js** global variable and ember.js generally runs in the browser which will not have **process.env**

However, you can use **process.env** during the build process which will produce ember app with the env variables build-in which you can access in another way.

I'm not sure what tooling you are using but here is how it works in Ember CLI Deploy:

http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v1.0.x/using-env-for-secrets/

And here is an example with webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/